# Elseif in WordPress with three outputs (third one doesn't show up)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, shortcode

Can't get this to work, been trying different things - but it only shows the two first. The last one (the else) doesn't show up on the website.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this one?

Thank you! :)

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ends', true) ) { ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ends', true); ?>

<?php } elseif ( shortcode_exists( 'postexpirator' ) ) { ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[postexpirator]'); ?>

<?php } else { ?>
Continues
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's getting hung up on:

```
<?php } elseif ( shortcode_exists( 'postexpirator' ) ) { ?>
```

And checking if the shortcode exists in general? I'm not too sure how you have this setup because it's a shortcode but I think that is probably what it is.